# Finding total number of self avoiding paths for $n\times n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

we call a connected part of $n\times n$ grid "N-mino" if it has these 2 conditions

1. it should contain $(n,n)$
2. if it contains $(i,j)$ then it should contains at least one of $(i+1,j)$ or $(i,j+1)$.

Find number of N-mino for a $n\times n$ grid.

For example: if $n=1$, there's just 1 such path , if $n=2$ there are 7 paths.
thnq in advanced ^_^.

Comment: 1. It seems to me that "connected" in the definition is superfluous, since in any N-mino, there is a path from every point to $(n,n)$.
2. I don't understand why you mentioned "self avoiding paths" in the title.

Comment: N-minos aren't necessarily _paths_. Perhaps you could explain why you refer to them as "paths".

Answer (score 3):

What you call "N-minos" are normally called [directed polyominoes](https://oeis.org/A005773). There is quite a large literature on them.
Perhaps [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4415v1) is a useful general starting point.

However, I'm not aware of them being counted by bounding box size before (usually by size or perimeter).
Using Mathematica, it appears the first few terms of the series are $1, 7, 79, 2007, 131311$.